# Isolate part of string value in report builder - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In a report I am using a field called fields!strvalue.value

When I put it into my report, the field splits into three data parts:

time part - address part - name part

I have tried various methods, eg =Left(Fields!strvalue.value,InStr(Fields!strvalue.value & ",",",")-1) in an attempt to isolate the time part. However when I do this, all three parts still appear in the report. I am not sure how to isolate just this one part.

I want to isolate the time part to help sort the report and to also set a parameter that runs off the time part.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated: thanks.

Comment: Is the exact format of *strvalue* like `time part - address part - name part`? i.e. delimited by `-`? Can you please give an example field value with actual data?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Looking at it more closely, when I add strValue to a report just by itself, it is sorting the data by number first. The first value to appear is a time value, 08:00 - 12:00, then addresses appear which have house numbers ranging from 1 to 119 then the time value 13:00 - 18:00 then house numbers , eg 136. Finally, the name part appears at the bottom.    So in other words, it seems to be sorting numerically. I just need to extract, somehow, 08:00 - 12:00 and 13:00 - 18:00.

Comment: To further clarify, when I run the report the data runs as:

Column heading is strvalue then the data appears vertically:

08:00 - 12:00

1, Smith Street

17, Jones Street

98, The Mews

13:00 - 18:00

142, Smith Avenue

Mrs Smith 

Therefore it mixes the time and address values. Name appears at the bottom.

Ideally I would like to sort by time: 08:00 - 12:00 (first column) addresses (second column) name (third column).